# MVVM+Kotlin+Databinding best practice

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-databinding

I am building an app on MVVM+Kotlin+Databinding, and i have this situation i am stuck at.
I have `LoginFragment` which has a phone number edittext and a button,
Now i need to check if the phone number is empty or not when user clicks the button.
Normally i would do that by using this code in my fragment.

```
if(!binding!!.phone.text.isEmpty()) {
    //do something
}
```

But according to [experts](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) my view should not know anything about the business logic, Hence i need to have this check inside my viewModel.
so what should be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If you use a two-way binding directly to the ViewModel's field (LiveData/ObservableField) then you wouldn't need to access the View directly from the binding itself, i think -- in fact, that's most likely what databinding is *for*, and not just generating view refs :p

Comment: well i am somwhat confused there too, i mean there are some people who are making their viewmodel extend BaseObservable, while i am extending viewModel in my case, so i can't use bindable
Moreover with observableFields i am only able to update ui when data changes, but i also need to get the text from edittext when button is clicked, what's the correct way to do that?

Comment: You **always** get the text from the edit text, that's the magic of databinding. So you don't need to access the view anymore to obtain it. With newest Databinding, ViewModel should expose LiveData, and Binding should have a `setLifecycleOwner` method to which you can set whoever the ViewModel belongs to and it should work: as in, you should be able to use `LiveData<String>` field directly in the XML binding for example, if `ViewModel` is specified as a data/variable.

Comment: I'd give a real answer but I do not have a ready-made code sample for this case yet, I just kinda know how it's supposed to look :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the bet practice to achieve that (from my point of view):

In your layout add text watcher and text to your `EditText`

```
android:text="@{view_model.phone}"
app:addTextChangedListener="@{view_model.phoneWatcher}"
```

and on click method to your button

```
android:onClick="@{() -> view_model.save()}"
```

Inside the `ViewModel` you will have text observable and a watcher

```
val phone = ObservableField<String?>()

val phoneWatcher = object : TextWatcherAdapter() {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        phone.set(s?.toString())
    }
}
```

Now you can make your check inside `ViewModel`

```
fun save() {
    if (phone.get()?.isNotEmpty == true) {
        // TODO: do something
    }
}
```

Also please note that it is a best practice to avoid doing something like that `binding!!.phone` in Kotlin. If you're using `!!` to make a possible nullable object look like it is not-nullable (even if you're 100% sure it is) - you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply but i did find using textwatcher as a solution to the question, but according to this blog: https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-data-binding-f9f9d3afc761
using textwatchers is not optimal and just as @EpicPandaForce stated in his comments to my question, the best solution for this may involve livedata but i don't know how to use it in this case

Comment: In the post you have linked there is no real reason regarding why this is not a good solution using `TextWatcher`, the only they mentioned is that you'll need to unsubscribe from it, but with the ViewModel it's not the case. The LiveData is not designed to work with views itselfs, you will have to transit value through fragment or activity.

Answer (score 0):

if you know how to use two way databinding you can directly check in the view model like this
In your layout in EdittextView

```
android:text="@={view_model.phone}"
```

Inside the ViewModel you will have text observable variable

```
val phone = ObservableField<String?>()
```

Now you can add if check inside save funtion in ViewModel like this

```
fun save() {
    if (phone.get()?.isNotEmpty == true) {
        // TODO: do something what you want to do
    }
}
```